# How to obtain the last word of a string

Tags: php

we have that string:

```
"I like to eat apple"
```

How can I obtain the result `"apple"` ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
// Your string
$str = "I like to eat apple";
// Split it into pieces, with the delimiter being a space. This creates an array.
$split = explode(" ", $str);
// Get the last value in the array.
// count($split) returns the total amount of values.
// Use -1 to get the index.
echo $split[count($split)-1];
```

Comment: Note that this doesn't account for punctuation; e.g. a trailing period will be included in the word.

Comment: You can just echo `array_pop($split)`

Answer (score 9):

a bit late to the party but this works too

```
$last = strrchr($string,' ');
```

as per http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_strrchr.asp

Answer (score 4):

```
$str = 'I like to eat apple';
echo substr($str, strrpos($str, ' ') + 1); // apple
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
$str = "I like to eat apple";
end((explode(" ",$str));
```

Comment: @Shehabix Not anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$array = explode(' ',$sentence);
$last = $array[count($array)-1];
```

Answer (score 1):

Get last word of string

$string ="I like to eat apple";
   $las_word_start = strrpos($string, ' ') + 1; // +1 so we don't include the    space in our result
   $last_word = substr($string, $last_word_start);
     echo $last_word // last word : apple

Comment: This won't work correctly for strings that don't have spaces, e.g. `"Hello"`

Answer (score 0):

How about this get last words or simple get last word from string just by passing the amount of words you need `get_last_words(1,  $str);`

```
public function get_last_words($amount, $string)
{
    $amount+=1;
    $string_array = explode(' ', $string);
    $totalwords= str_word_count($string, 1, 'àáãç3');
    if($totalwords > $amount){
        $words= implode(' ',array_slice($string_array, count($string_array) - $amount));
    }else{
        $words= implode(' ',array_slice($string_array, count($string_array) - $totalwords));
    }

    return $words;
}
$str = 'I like to eat apple';
echo get_last_words(1,  $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
// your string
$str = 'I like to eat apple';

// used end in explode, for getting last word
$str_explode=end(explode("|",$str));
echo    $str_explode;

?>
```

Output will be `apple`.