# Get the last word of a string

Tags: php, string

I have tried a few things to get a last part out
I done this:

```
$string = 'Sim-only 500 | Internet 2500';
preg_replace("Sim-Only ^([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])$ | Internet ","",$string
AND
preg_match("/[^ ]*$/","",{abo_type[1]})
```

The first one won't work and the second returns an array but a realy need  string.

Comment: Can you please specify what you actually want? Just the last word of any string? In this case the 2500?

Comment: Yes i want the 2500, and yes i want i any case the last word.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get last string in sentences using php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11029447/how-to-get-last-string-in-sentences-using-php)

Comment: You might find [`array_pop(s($str)->words())`](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Str/blob/8fd0c608d5496d43adaa899642c1cce047e076dc/src/Str.php#L363) helpful, as found in [this standalone library](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Str).

Answer (score 77, accepted):

If you're after the last word in a sentence, why not just do something like this?

```
$string = '​Sim-only 500 ​| Internet 2500';
$pieces = explode(' ', $string);
$last_word = array_pop($pieces);

echo $last_word;
```

I wouldn't recommend using regular expressions as it's unnecessary, unless you really want to for some reason.

```
$string = 'Retrieving the last word of a string using PHP.';
preg_match('/[^ ]*$/', $string, $results);
$last_word = $results[0]; // $last_word = PHP.
```

Using a `substr()` method would be better than both of these if resources/efficiency/overhead is a concern.

```
$string = 'Retrieving the last word of a string using PHP.';
$last_word_start = strrpos($string, ' ') + 1; // +1 so we don't include the space in our result
$last_word = substr($string, $last_word_start); // $last_word = PHP.
```

it is faster, although it really doesn't make that much of a difference on things like this. If you're constantly needing to know the last word on a 100,000 word string, you should probably be going about it in a different way.

Comment: So, you will created a 1000 length array from a 1000-word sentence just to get the last word?

Comment: @Sebastian Context matters, but in case of 1,000 words, yes I probably still would. Unless you're running the script thousands/millions of times, the amount of time you'd save doing it another way in comparison to this way wouldn't be more than the amount of time I took to write this comment.

Comment: Your last example misses the first letter when there is only one word in the string. Fixed code is: $last_word = substr($string, strrpos(' ' . $string, ' '));

Answer (score 9):

This should work for you:

```
$str = "fetch the last word from me";
$last_word_start = strrpos ( $str , " ") + 1;
$last_word_end = strlen($str) - 1;
$last_word = substr($str, $last_word_start, $last_word_end);
```

Comment: You do not need `$last_word_end` here. When the third parameter of `substr` is omitted, the function takes everything from `$last_word_start` to the end of the string. If you insist on having it, then it should be `$last_word_end = strlen($str) - $last_word_start` (yours usually won't give a wrong result, but it is meaningless; it WILL be wrong if the string contains no whitespaces).

Answer (score 6):

It depends on what you try to do (it is hard to understand from your description) but to get the last word from a string you can do:

```
$split = explode(" ", $string);

echo $split[count($split)-1];
```

See [How to obtain the last word of a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11029447/how-to-get-last-string-in-sentences-using-php) for more information.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to wrap the last word with a span:

```
<?php
/**
 * Wrap last word with span
 * @author: Elron
 * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18612872/get-the-last-word-of-a-string
 */
function wrap_last_word($string) {
    // Breaks string to pieces
    $pieces = explode(" ", $string);

    // Modifies the last word
    $pieces[count($pieces)-1] = '<span class="is-last-word">' . $pieces[count($pieces)-1] . '</span>';

    // Returns the glued pieces
    return implode(" ", $pieces);
}

wrap_last_word('hello this is wrapped');
// returns this:
// hello this is <span class="is-last-word">wrapped</span>
```

Answer (score 3):

The existing solutions all work fine, but I wanted a one-liner. `explode()` will split a sentence into words, but trying to pass it directly into `array_pop()` or `end()` gives a "Only variables should be passed by reference" notice. [`array_slice()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) to the rescue:

```
$string = 'Sim-only 500 | Internet 2500';
echo array_slice(explode(' ', $string), -1)[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

There you go a generic function to get last words from string

```
public function get_last_words($amount, $string)
{
    $amount+=1;
    $string_array = explode(' ', $string);
    $totalwords= str_word_count($string, 1, 'àáãç3');
    if($totalwords > $amount){
        $words= implode(' ',array_slice($string_array, count($string_array) - $amount));
    }else{
        $words= implode(' ',array_slice($string_array, count($string_array) - $totalwords));
    }

    return $words;
}
$string = '​Sim-​only 500 | Internet 2500​';
echo get_last_words(1,  $string );
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to get the last word from a string

```
$my_string = "fetch the last word from me";
 
// Explode the string into an array
$my_string = explode(" ", $my_string);

// target the last word with end() function 
$my_string = end($my_string);

echo $my_string;
```

Result `me`

Answer (score 0):

One-line solution using regexp:

```
preg_replace('/.*\s/', '', $string);
```

This suppress everything ending by a space, and since regexp are always matched "as long as possible", this will match everything but the last word.
This has also the advantage on working with any "space" character (tab, newline...).

But the best performance/ressources consumption solution is (does not work if only one word):

```
substr($string, strrpos($string, ' ') + 1);
```

Comment: this may not work if $string contains only one word

Comment: You're right indeed for my 2nd option.

Answer (score 0):

There is a one-line solution.

```
basename(str_replace(' ', '/', 'hello world'));
```

will return world

Answer (score -1):

Just use this function

```
function last_word($string)
{
    $pieces = explode(' ', $string);
    return array_pop($pieces);
}
```