# How to extract the last 4 words from a string?

Tags: php

I would like to extract the last 4 words from a string as a single chunk.

For example, if I have:

```
"Are You Looking For The Best Website Review"
```

I'd like to catch the last four words as:

```
"The Best Website Review"
```

I only have basic coding knowledge and have tried every variation I could find within this forum.

The closest I've come is by using the suggestion of [Rick Kuipers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11029447/how-to-obtain-the-last-word-of-a-string) ([How to obtain the last word of a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11029447/how-to-obtain-the-last-word-of-a-string)) but this gives me the words as individual values.

```
$split = explode(" ", $str);

echo $split[count($split)-4];
echo $split[count($split)-3];
echo $split[count($split)-2];
echo $split[count($split)-1];
```

My coding knowledge is limited so any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Use `join` or `implode` to glue items that you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use `str_word_count` along with the `array_splice` like as

```
$str = "Are You Looking For The Best Website Review";
$arr = str_word_count($str,1);
echo implode(' ',array_splice($arr,-4));
```

**Edited**

If your text contains `Are-You-Looking-For-The-Best-Website-Review` `hiphen` the you can use `str_replace` like as

```
$arr = str_word_count(str_replace('-',' ',$str),1);
echo implode(' ',array_splice($arr,-4));
```

[**Demo**](https://3v4l.org/usAUV)

Comment: Thank you for such a quick reply. This works perfectly. However I forgot to mention that one version of my titles contains hypens i.e Are-You-Looking-For-The-Best-Website-Review. Is it possible to adjust your code to work with these?

Comment: Updated my answer @Codex

Comment: Uchiha, that's perfect. I can't ask for anymore. Again, thank you for sharing your valuable knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a simple regular expression for this:

```
<?php

$subject = "Are You Looking For The Best Website Review";
$pattern = '/(\w+\s+\w+\s+\w+\s+\w+)\s*$/u';
preg_match($pattern, $subject, $tokens);

var_dump($tokens[0]);
```

The output is:

```
string(23) "The Best Website Review"
```

This also has the advantage that the type and number of whitespaces between words is irrelevant and trailing whitespaces at the end of the string are ignored.

---

Edit: considering your comment to the answer posted by @Uchiha this is a variant of the pattern that shows how you can easily match words delimited by other characters apart from whitespaces:

```
$pattern = '/(\w+[-\s]+\w+[-\s]+\w+[-\s]+\w+)\s*$/u';
```

Comment: arkascha, also thanks for the quick solution. I can't believe how quickly this problem was solved.

Comment: @Codex I added a variant of the pattern that shows how you can easily match words delimited by other characters than whitespaces. Hope this helps. And frankly, I have no idea why one should prefer the more complex and less efficient approach using the combination of normal string methods...

Comment: Arkascha, thanks again for taking the time provide an additional refinement to your code. This has been a very positive outcome to something I thought would take much longer to achieve.

Comment: Great if we could help with this. You should then accept an answer if your issue has been solved. Have fun!

Comment: I liked your solution from the beginning only+1