# How to get last n words from a sentence?

Tags: php

I would like to get last n (for e.g. last 5) words of a sentence. How can I get it ? The following code gives the desired result but for this requires to count the remaining words in the sentence.

```
<?php
$string = "This is an example to get last five words from this sentence";
$pieces = explode(" ", $string);
echo $first_part = implode(" ", array_splice($pieces, 0,7));
echo "<hr/>";
echo $other_part = implode(" ", array_splice($pieces, 0));
?>
```

I was hoping if there is a direct way of do this like to [get first n words from a sentence](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5956635).

*NOTE:* This is not the duplicate of [How to obtain the last word of a string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11029470/9552432). I want last **n words**, not last **nth** word.

Comment: You could just change `7` to `count($pieces) - $wordsNeeded`

Comment: @u_mulder Sorry buddy, but it seems you have an confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For last 5

```
$string = "This is an example to get last five words from this sentence";
$pieces = explode(" ", $string);
echo $first_part = implode(" ", array_splice($pieces, -5));
```

Comment: This works. But I am going to do bit more research if this could be made more simpler as this answer requires three diffrent function (explode, implode, and array_splice) to do the task.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this

```
<?php
$string = "This is an example to get last five words from this sentence";
$pieces = explode(" ", $string);
$yourValue = 5; //set for how many words you want.
$count = count($pieces) - $yourValue;//this will do its job so you don't have to count.
echo $first_part = implode(" ", array_splice($pieces, 0,$count));
echo "<hr/>";
echo $other_part = implode(" ", array_splice($pieces, 0));
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

isn't this what you are looking for?

```
$nWord = 3;
$string = "This is an example to get last five words from this sentence";
$arr = explode(" ",$string);
$output = array_slice(array_reverse($arr), 0, $nWord);
$output = implode(" ", $output);
print_r($output);
```

Comment: Sorry buddy but if you run your code (I have added implode now), the output is **"sentence this from words five"** which is also in reverse.

Comment: i just thought of returning n words not the pattern of returning. Sorry for that and thank you very much @TimPaine